# Separating data in excel cells with php

Tags: php, csv

I'm trying to write some data from a database into a .csv file. The data contains three columns. Now everything goes well, I can get the data and write it into the .csv file, but I also want the data to be separated into different columns. For example:

Database columns: Firstname, Lastname, Age.
.csv file columns: A, B, C
Firstname in A
Lastname is B
Age in C

I've tried \t, which didn't work. I've searched the internet for solutions but it didn't deliver me any clear description. I'm pretty new to PHP, so it's not that easy for me to get the right data for me out an example of 2000 lines.

Are there other options or did I screw up something?

EDIT:

```
include ('db.php');

$con = $db_con;

$query = "SELECT * FROM persons";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$file = "write.csv";
$open = fopen($file, 'w');
$count = 0;
fputcsv($open, array('FirstName', 'LastName', 'Age'));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $persons[$num]['FirstName']         =   $row['FirstName'];
    $persons[$num]['LastName']      =   $row['LastName'];
    $persons[$num]['Age']           =   $row['Age'];
    $count++;

    foreach($persons as $person){
    fputcsv($open, $person);
    } 
}
fclose($open);
mysqli_close($con);
```

Doesn't contain any attempt of me trying to separate data.

Comment: Show code... this is a pretty trivial task using fputcsv()... but note that MS Excel uses a locale-specific separator if you open the file using a double-click, while you can define whatever separator you want when using MS Excel `import` and it will then ask you what separator character you are using

Comment: Edited my post with fputcsv

Comment: Your Excel locale separator is most likely to be either a comma (,) or a semi-colon (;)

Comment: After searching for a while on that separator thing I found out that, when you open the .csv file in notepad and just add sep=, above the cell information, the cells splitted up. Just changing the separator in my configuration didn't work, but thanks to your suggestion I found where I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Fetch your data from database into array..

```
<?php

$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Select only the columns you want in your SQL query

```
$query = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, Age FROM persons";
```

and then loop through the results writing your CSV

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $persons[$num]['FirstName']         =   $row['FirstName'];
    $persons[$num]['LastName']      =   $row['LastName'];
    $persons[$num]['Age']           =   $row['Age'];
    $count++;

    fputcsv($open, $result);
}
```

and unless you want to use it elsewhere in the code, you don't even need to bother with the $persons array